# How To: Redirect from MVC .NET website to MVC .NET Core subsite without user having to 'relog'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have a MVC ASP.NET site that uses a database lookup for user authentication and then stores authentication variables in cookies.

I want to redirect the user to a MVC ASP.NET Core subsite without the user losing his authentication variables.

I am not able to share cookies between the two sites due to different encryption-schemes.

Both sites are hosted on the same domain on a windows server (IIS). Is there any way to *securely* transfer data along with the url redirect?

Is there some obvious solution that i am missing?
Please let me know if you need additional information about the project.

As a temporary solution, the user is promted for a new login once he is redirected to the subsite. I wish to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

You can not share data from MVC web app to MVC core web app. That is because it is hard to do.

But, there is a way to share the authentication mechanism. You can have an identity provider which will be responsible for authentication of users in both the sites. The login functionality will be in the identity server. Once a user is logged in, both your sites will use those authentication data.

Comment: I see. I do have an API endpoint for authentication, that both sites can use. My problem is to identify the user, once i redirect him. I have no "session data" once i redirect, and therefor i cannot even use the authentication endpoint without promting the user to enter his credentials once more